# Why doesn't the stackView I've created show up?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

```
class EventsCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setUpCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
      let container = UIView()
        container.frame = eventImage.frame
        container.addSubview(eventImage)
        container.layer.masksToBounds = false
        container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        extensionSetConstraintsWithFormat(horizontalFormat: "|[v0]|", verticalFormat: "|[v0]|", views: [eventImage])
        container.extensionSetShadowEasy(color: UIColor.black.cgColor), offSet: CGSize(width: 0, height: 3))
      return container
    }()

    let eventImage: UIImageView = {
        let eventView = UIImageView()
        eventView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        eventView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        eventView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        eventView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        eventView.image = UIImage(named: "Event")
        return eventView
    }()

    let usersStackView: UIStackView = {
        let stack = UIStackView()
        stack.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.axis = .horizontal
        stack.distribution = .fillProportionally
        stack.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        stack.extensionSetShadowEasy(color: UIColor.black.cgColor), offSet: CGSize(width: 0, height: 3))
        return stack
    }()


    func setUpCell(){
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        extensionSetShadowEasy(color: UIColor.black.cgColor), offSet: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        addSubview(containerView)
        addSubview(usersStackView)

        extensionSetConstraintsWithFormat(horizontalFormat: "|-10-[v0]-10-|", verticalFormat: "|-10-[v0(200)][v1(50)]-10-|", views: [containerView, usersStackView])
        extensionSetConstraintsWithFormat(horizontalFormat: "|-10-[v0]-10-|", verticalFormat: nil, views: [usersStackView])


    }

}
```

I'm trying to add a UIStackView to a collectionViewCell but it simply doesn't show up, I have no idea what's missing in my code, I set the constraints but it seems not to work, other views can be added just stack view doesn't appear...

the function I use to add the constraints is an extensions I created but I already tested it multiple times and it works perfectly.

I'm creating everything by code for learning purposes no storyboard being used just code..

thanks in advance for the answers) sorry for my bad code, I'm a beginner...

Comment: Do not directly add subviews to the cell itself. The cell manages multiple layers of content, of which the content view is only one. - have a look on documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewcell

Comment: Did you actually try adding any subviews to the UIStackView?  Stack view is a non-rendering sub-class of UIView.  Setting background color on it to orange won't do anything as well.  Decent article on that on [Use Your Loaf] (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stack-view-background-color/)

Answer (score 1):

My experience tells me that you can't render the UIStackView because it's empty, if a UIStackView is without any child it will not get rendered, so it doesn't matter if you set a background color or any other properties because they won't show.

If you want to show a background even if the UIStackView is empty, you can replace it with a UIView and inside of it put the UIStackView, just add constraints and properties accordingly. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @ascentman mentioned, do not directly add subviews to the cell, instead add views on contentView.

```
func setUpCell(){
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        extensionSetShadowEasy(color: UIColor.black.cgColor), offSet: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5))
        contentView.addSubview(containerView)
        contentView.addSubview(usersStackView)

        extensionSetConstraintsWithFormat(horizontalFormat: "|-10-[v0]-10-|", verticalFormat: "|-10-[v0(200)][v1(50)]-10-|", views: [containerView, usersStackView])
        extensionSetConstraintsWithFormat(horizontalFormat: "|-10-[v0]-10-|", verticalFormat: nil, views: [usersStackView])

    }
```

Try this may be it will helpful for you.

Is other views are visible or not? If other views are visible then check constraints, size of your stack view in 3D debuger. May be because of constraint issue its size sets zero or its showing out of cell.

Answer (score 0):

Your EventsCell might be initialized with CGRectZero frame. i.e make sure you update frames of the cell's subviews in layoutSubviews method.